# Modifying Plone Translation Content

Tags: internationalization, plone

I assume that Plone has the base "system" messages stored in the Data.fs file (Zope DB?).  Meaning, the text shown, for example, when you log out (in English) says "You are now logged out".  This is stored somewhere in the Zope DB.

Is there a way to change what the content of these messages say?  We have a Russian translation of the site which we'd like to modify the "You are now logged out" message - but I cannot find it anywhere in the ZMI or the filesystem.

If my assumptions are correct, and they are stored in the Zope DB, is there a good utility for browsing/modifying this content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plone uses Zope's translation service and standard [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) utilities for this task.

The best tutorial on i18n and l10n available is [Internationalization in Plone 3.3 and 4.0](http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2010/10/i18n-plone-4) by Maurits van Rees.

Check specifically the [Overriding translations](http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2010/10/i18n-plone-4#overriding-translations) part.